# Generate multiple types with multiple csv

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to generate various types in the same index based on various csv. As I don´t know the amount of csv, making an input for each one would be non-viable.
So does anyone know how to generate types with the names of the files and in those, introduce the csv respectively?

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/home/user/Documents/data/*.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  } 
}


filter { 
    
    csv {
        separator => ","
        skip_header => "true"
        autodetect_column_names => true
        autogenerate_column_names => true
    }
}

output {
   elasticsearch {
     hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
     index => "final_index"

  }

stdout {}

}
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having multiple document structures in the same index has been removed in Elasticsearch indices since version 6, if a document is not looking the same way as the index is templated it will not be able to send the data to it, what you can do is make sure that all fields are known and you have one general template containing all possible fields.

Is there a reason why you want all of it in one index?

If it is for querying purposes or Kibana, do know you can wildcard when searching and have patterns for Kibana.

**Update after your comment:**

Use a filter to extract the filename using grok

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => ["path","%{GREEDYDATA}/%{GREEDYDATA:filename}\.csv"]
  }
}
```

And use the filename in your output like this:

```
elasticsearch {
   hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
   index => "final_index-%{[filename]}"
}
```

Comment: What I want to do is to automatically save data from those csv. I don´t mind if they are in the same index or in different indexes. In that case, I don´t care if they get saved in different indexes if those indexes are saved with the csv filename. In other words, one index for each file (.csv).

Comment: Updated my answer with some snippets based on your feedback

Comment: Okay, thanks again. One thing to mention: When I use that code it works well but the name of the indexes doesn´t change, I think that´s because I get the following error `"_grokparsefailure"`. :´(

Comment: that means that there is an issue with the pattern versus the path, can you give me an example of the path where the `"_grokparsefailure"` happened?

Comment: Yes it worked! :) Now the problem that I get is that the columns that I upload are the same for the different files (.csv), when the columns must be different. The columns from the first file get repeated among the rest files. (The columns of the different files are different, so this makes no sense)

Comment: To answer that question it is caused by the fact that this is the general way of working of the csv filter plugin as it will remember the fieldnames upon the very first event seen in that pipeline. If you want to separate this the only way of using the autodetection will be having a separate pipeline for each filename you can have or you could create different csv filters based on the filename (if known up front...)